# Submit a form and display the result contained in a JSON file, via JQuery

Tags: jquery, python, json, flask, jqueryform

Once submitted a form containing a list of numbers, I need to extract (from a `JSON` file) the result of a simple calculation, performed on that list and output that result inside a `<div></div>` tag, in the current page.

Here below the Flask Python code with the submitted list of numbers obtained via `getlist`. The result of the calculation is finally converted into `JSON`via `jsonify`.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

data = [
('t', 0, 'a'),
('t', 0, 'b'),
('t', 0, 'c'),
('t', 0, 'd')
]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    entries=[]
    for (i,v) in enumerate(data):
        entries.append(data[i][2])
    return render_template('test.html', entries=entries)


@app.route('/_numbers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def numbers():
    a = request.form.getlist('a')
    print a
    L=0
    v=0
    an=0
    for L,v in enumerate(a):
        an+=float(v)
    return jsonify(res=an)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

test.html file looks like:

```
{% extends "test0.html" %}
{% block body %}

<h2>Get the sum of 4 numbers</h2>
<form action="{{ url_for('numbers')}}" method=post>
    {% for L in entries %}

              <input type=float size=5 name=a>

              {% if loop.last==True %}             
                  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Calc" id="calculate"> 
                  </form>
              {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Upon submitting, I get the correct answer in the form of a `JSON` file (e.g.):

```
{
  "res": 10.0
}
```

How to extract the obtained value and display it via JQuery ? I've tried `getJSON` but with no success. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert the result in the current page then you have to submit the form over Ajax, and then you get the JSON response in the completion callback.

Take a look at the [AjaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) plugin for jQuery, which can transform the submit button in your HTML form to an Ajax submit. Below is a short example adapted from the plugin's documentation:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(response) { 
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            $('#someDiv').innerHTML = result.res
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Having tempted your solution, I get the following error on FireBug: `TypeError: result is null
 

$('#result').innerHTML = result.res`

Comment: What is the value of `response`? That should be what you returned from your Flask view function.

Comment: this is what I get : `response=Object { res=10}`

Comment: Ah great! it is already converted into an object. Then you just need to do `$('#someDiv').innerHTML = response.res`, the parseJSON line is not necessary.

Comment: Well, there's a progress, I do not have anymore errors, thanks. However, my `div` stays empty: no way to display the result on my current page.

Comment: That could be a selector problem, it's definitely not related to getting the JSON response. Add the HTML for your result element and the code that you are using to insert it and maybe I can help you with that as well.

Comment: HTML is the following `<div id="result"></div>
`. Here the code `<script>      
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(response) { 
            $('#result').innerHTML = response.res 
        });
    }); 
</script>` Thanks again...

Comment: I think I found the solution: one should replace `$('#result').innerHTML = response.res` with `$('#result').html(response.res)`. What do you think ?

Comment: `html()` should be equivalent to `innerHTML` on most browsers, maybe the browser that you are using does not have innerHTML?

Comment: Well I don't know...anyway I am happy that it works now ! Thanks